# how to backup outlook express signature

Tags: backup, outlook-express, email-signature

i know how to backup outlook signature but

can i know how can i transfer outlook express signature to other computer?

the signatures are not text, its HTML signature with some image.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to save it to a text file and then e-mail it, copy it to USB stick or even floppy disk. Then on the other computer open the text file and copy the text into the signature box.

Comment: the signatures are not text, its HTML signature with some image.

Comment: @user20989 - you still should be able to copy out the source of the signature (after all you can edit it). The fact that it's HTML doesn't stop it being saved to a text file - after all a HTML file is just a text file with a different extension.